# 1 declaration needs attention - Google Play Console

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-console

I am getting error stating "
Some sections have errors, or aren't complete" and I am not sure which section has error.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Yesterday I had an issue related to QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES, but now I was going to follow this tutorial to fix it ( https://web.archive.org/web/20220811110813/https://flutterhq.com/questions-and-answers/2907/updating-an-app-that-has-sensitive-permissions-on-the-google-play-console ), but I can't since the page seems broken

Comment: Are you using the owner account of your Google developer profile?

Comment: I hate to just be a "Me too", but I've had this for a while: can't push any updates, and can't seem to get any clarification from Google. I'm stumped.

Comment: I got this form link from the Google Play Console to contact with the policy center: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/appwarning?hl=en&authuser=0

Comment: @MikalaiDaronin Yes I am... I got in contact with Google via chat. Couldn't fix it, now they are "looking into it" and keeping communications via email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having same issue and from last 2 days it was not showing any error and Today I am able to see the Sensitive permissions and API is remaining from my side. So issue is from the Google side in Play Console. I have added reply at [Play Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/209568148/can-t-find-the-1-declaration-that-needs-attention-in-app-content-section?hl=en&authuser=1) thread.
[image]